# How to use add dot in Java's DecimalFormat to currency?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I'm trying to find a way to display currency with a dot so for instance it should be

*1.234,56 kr.*

At the moment I'm using

```
pattern = "#,##0.00 ¤";
new DecimalFormat(pattern);
```

This doesn't work as the Danish krone is for some reason defined there as kr instead of officially recognized kr.

I've looked for a way to escape these characters using Unicode value that I would add to pattern but that doesn't work. In the [official](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) documentation here I don't see a way to do it either.

TLDR: I want to add full stop after currency symbol. So at the moment I have it like this `kr` , what I want to get is `kr.` .

Comment: what is your input?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? From JDK9 onwards, it should output "kr." with a dot. If you're using a version before JDK9, then you're using a version that is outdated and unsupported. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210528

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thanks a lot yes this helps. I am using an older version and I don't have an option to update that, that is not up to me. This will help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the dot after the currency symbol you can set a custom currency symbol. Here I did it using euros (note that instead of "€." you can put my_symbol.getCurrencySymbol()+"." if you want it for all currency and not just one):

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols my_symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    my_symbol.setCurrencySymbol("€.");
    String pattern = "###,###.###¤";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat1 = new DecimalFormat(pattern, my_symbol);

    String format = decimalFormat1.format(987654321.321);
    System.out.println(format);
```

This gives

```
987.654.321,321€.
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood. At the moment I have something like 1.234,56 kr when I use the format that I posted. I want to add full stop after the kr part. So it would be 1.234,56 kr.

Everything here I want to know is how to add that dot after currency symbol.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Have a look now, it should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

The output of currency values depends on the respective country setting. If you want to explicitly have a decimal point as in your case, you have to set a corresponding locale for the `Numberformat`. E.g. English for a point.

For Example:

```
public String FormatWithPoint(double yourValue){
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    return nf.format(yourValue);
}
```

**Edit:** If you need more control, you can also do the following:

```
public String FormatCurreny(double yourValue){
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setCurrencySymbol("kr.");
    dfs.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator('.');
    ((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    return nf.format(yourValue);
}
```